# Powertop strange results

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management, wifi

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 and battery life decreased by 2 times. Powertop documentation says that there should be 3 wakeups per second, I have 800-900. I think it's very strange because I didn't touch any settings except for disabling nvidia graphic card.
[image] 
How can i improve battery life?

Comment: `ath9k` is a wifi driver. Was any program using the wifi connection at the time? Do you see the same numbers if you turn off the wifi connection?

Comment: with wifi disabled wakeups decreases till 200-400 and ath9k is not in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is Chrome: [Chromium Generates HUGE numbers of CPU wakeups and uses massive amounts of power](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77625) (Chromium is the community version of Chrome)

Change to other browser.

Comment: Ah, good to know. What other browser do you suggest? In my experience Firefox takes a lot more CPU to render a page, so in addition to being slower, it uses more power for rendering. My gut feeling is that Firefox may still be more power-efficient, but it would be worth measuring.

Comment: Firefox has better results than Chrome in the bug report. In Phoronix the results are the opposite http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_browser_power&num=1. Depends of the number of open tabs. I use Firefox7 in my netbook and the performance/consumption is very good (400 open tabs). A tip is use Panorama and other is change the preference "browser.sessionstore.max_concurrent_tabs" to 0.

Comment: And yes, Firefox will be more efficient and fast because to the actual works in GPU rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that "SignalSender" is responsible for most of the wakeups.  Shut down that program.